# How to open pdf in PdfRenderer in andorid 5.0 from internal file path data/data/com.xyz/file.pdf

Tags: android, pdf, android-5.0-lollipop, parcelfiledescriptor

I want to use PdfRenderer to get pdf first page `Bitmap` in android 5.0 and above .

But i am unable to get `ParcelFileDescriptor` of internal file in android .

any one known how to convert `FileInputStream` to `ParcelFileDescriptor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a `ParcelFileDescriptor` on a `File`, call [the static `open()` method on `ParcelFileDescriptor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor.html#open%28java.io.File,%20int%29).